# Как использовать один и тот же объект модели в разных шаблонах. Python. Django

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго дня, столкнулся с проблемой при работе с моделями в **Django** **Python**.

У меня имеется такая модель, в которой содержится единственное поле - Name:

**models.py**

```
class GroupModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Группа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Группы'
```

Которую я использую для вывода наименований групп, в подменю навпанели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так это отображение у меня прописано в шаблоне:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'groups' %}">{{ group.name }}</a></li> 
{% endfor %}
```

В качестве groups используется переменная из контекстного процессора который подключен в **settings.py**:

```
def add_variable_to_context(request):
    return {
        'groups': GroupModel.objects.order_by('id').all(),
        'subjects': SubjectModel.objects.order_by("id").all(),
        'teachers': User.objects.filter(groups__name='teachers').order_by("id").all(),
    }
```

И уже в следующем шаблоне пытаюсь вывести выбранную мной группу, но вывод не удается:

```
<div class="head_load_sheet">
    <h1>Часы группы {{group.name}} за месяц</h1>
</div>
```

Выводится только: "Часы группы за месяц":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вью первой страницы:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')
```

Вью второй страницы:

```
def groups(request):
    return render(request, 'main/deportament/groups.html')
```

mapping в urls:

```
 path('deportament/groups/<int:group>/', groups, name='groups'),
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно я могу оформить такую работу с моделью и разными шаблонами?

Comment: @RomanKonoval 2 разных шаблона да, во вьюхе я не передаю никакой контекст данных беру его из контекстного процессора

Comment: @RomanKonoval
Поправил, изменил текст вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В контекст добавляется список групп с ключом `groups`, а в шаблоне вы пытаетесь читать значение с ключом `group`.

Конечно его там нет. В первом шаблоне `group` появляется благодаря циклу:

```
{% for group in groups %}
```

При переходе по ссылке откуда сервер узнает, какую группу пользователь выбрал? Чтоб показать конкретную группу, нужно чтобы в url, который ведет на страницу показа группы, был параметр с идентификатором группы.

Нужно добавить параметр в urlconf в `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('departament/groups/<int:groupid>/', views.groups),
]
```

и потом задавать его в шаблоне в `url`:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'groups' id=group.id%}">{{ group.name }}</a></li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Теперь идентификатор будет доступен в параметрах view:

```
def groups(request, groupid):
  group = Group.objects.get(id=groupid)
  ...
```

И придется группу положить в контекст, чтоб она стала доступна в шаблоне.

Comment: И как я могу это недорозумение поправить?
передавать контекст данных в эти две вью - Index и Groups? 
Тогда при переходе на объект модели Index на странице Index я увижу этот же объект на странице Groups?

Comment: Для начала нужно понять чего вы хотите добиться? У вас есть список. А отображать вы пробуете одну группу? Какую именно, если в списке их будет 10?

Comment: На страницу Index я планирую отображать все группы какие у меня есть вы выпадающем меню, после выбора нужной группы я попадаю на страницу Groups и хочу видеть в заголовке <h1> отображение той группы которую я выбрал

Comment: А можете уточнить пожалуйста, каким образом можно добавить mapping в urls.py?
Могу таким образом, отметил в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил по памяти, но лучше почитать документацию.

Comment: Получилось отобразить, далее столкнулся с похожей проблемой, у меня при переходе на страницe - deportament/groups/<int:group_id>
Есть кнопка которая ведет на еще одну страницу с этой же группой 
Попытался также указать маппинг по аналогии с вашим советом, на что стал получать ошибку:
Reverse for 'redactor_group' with arguments '(<GroupModel: ПКС-401>,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deportament/groups/(?P<group_id>[0-9]+)/redactor_group$']
Могу расширить свой вопрос или лучше новый задать?

Comment: Лучше новый. Так смысл вопроса совсем теряется, а тут совершенно другая проблема.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286891
Создал.