# Ошибка при работе с одним объектом модели в нескольких шаблонах Django Python

Tags: python, django

В соответствии с ответом @RomanKornoval в вопросе - [Как использовать один и тот же объект модели в разных шаблонах. Python. Django](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1286703), получилось настроить переход на страницу. И использовать один и тот же объект модели в разных шаблонах.

Но далее столкнулся с похожей проблемой, дело в том, что у меня есть еще один шаблон redactor_group, который ведет на следующую страницу, на которой пользователь может отредактировать группу, которую он выбрал из выпадающего списка.

url для шаблона redactor_group:

```
path('deportament/groups/<int:group_id>/redactor_group', redactor_group, name='redactor_group'),
```

Вью redactor_group:

```
def redactor_group(request,group_id):
groups = GroupModel.objects.all()
group_id = get_object_or_404(GroupModel, pk = group_id)
context = {"groups" : groups, "group_id" : group_id}
return render(request, "main/deportament/redactor/redactor_group.html",context)
```

Шаблон из которого переходим на redactor_view:

```
            <ul>
            <li><button onclick="window.location.href='{% url "redactor_group" group_id  %}'">Изменить</button></li>
            <li><button>Импорт</button></li>
            <li><button>Экспорт</button></li>
        </ul>
```

Шаблон redactor_view, где используется объект переданный из вью groups.

```
<h1>Часы группы {{ group_id }} за месяц</h1>
```

Ошибка, которую получаю при переходе:

```
Reverse for 'redactor_group' with arguments '(<GroupModel: ПКС-401>,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deportament/groups/(?P<group_id>[0-9]+)/redactor_group$']
```

вью redactor_group:

```
def redactor_group(request,group_id):
group = get_object_or_404(GroupModel, pk = group_id)
context = {"groups" : groups, "group" : group}
return render(request, "main/deportament/redactor/redactor_group.html",context)
```

groups.html:

```
<li><button onclick="window.location.href='{% url "redactor_group" group.id  %}'">Изменить</button></li>
```

Ошибка:

```
Reverse for 'redactor_group' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deportament/groups/(?P<group_id>[0-9]+)/redactor_group$']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы сохраняете объект `Group` под именем `group_id` и пробуете его использовать, как идентификатор.

Нужно или сохранять реально идентификатор:

```
group_id = get_object_or_404(GroupModel, pk = group_id).id
```

Или сохранять группу, но доставать идентификатор уже в шаблоне:

```
group = get_object_or_404(GroupModel, pk = group_id)
context = {"groups" : groups, "group" : group}
```

и в шаблоне:

```
<li><button onclick="window.location.href='{% url "redactor_group" group.id  %}'">Изменить</button></li>
```

Comment: Изменил вью redactor_group и шаблон, в соответствии с вашими рекоммендациями, пробую перейти в группу получаю ошибку отразил этот момент в вопросе

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо!